# check intel Graphic installation

Tags: intel, intel-graphics

hi i want to know whether my graphic card is installed or not ?
when i execute

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

it returns

```
OpenGL vendor string : Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string : Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string : 1.4 Mesa 8.0.5
OpenGL extensions:
```

so is the Intel(R) 945GME in renderer string means installed ?

Comment: Looks like. I usually check using "glxinfo | grep direct rendering" (or similar), looking for a line saying "direct rendering: yes/no". You can also check using glxgears, if it shows the gears, you graphic card is installed.

Answer (score 1):

similar to your command `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` also `glxinfo | grep render` if you'd like to check a short info on your graphics run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
```

if you want to see more advanced output:

```
sudo lspci -vnnk | grep -iA12 VGA
```